# Back to product page after Paypal auto return URL page

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal

[This is within Wordpress, if that's relevant]

I've implemented a custom Paypal auto return page =C. Looks good, lots of useful information for the purchaser immediately after purchase. 
I would like to include a link or button on that page (the page after Paypal) that takes the purchaser right back to the product(s) page they made the purchase from (the page before Paypal = A).

In other words

A --> B1/B2/etc Paypal confirmation and payment pages --> C Custom thank you page --> [Link] Back to A

Is this possible?
I've tried using standard Back methods but they seem to fall foul of the indeterminate number of intervening Paypal pages/URLs

Any suggestions would be most welcome. Thanks.